# How to add dynamic column in table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1. `item_table` (with attributes `{item_id , item_name}`)
2. `company_table` (with attribute `{cmpny_id , cmpny_name}`)

Each item (>1000) has a different selling price for different company (>500)

I want to create a table like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVUvN.png) (see also [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo7En.png)).

Is it possible to create table dynamically in SQL so that it require less memory space?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Can you clarify your sentence "Each item (>1000) has a different selling price for different company (>500)" specifically what >1000 and >500 means Can you share some sample data and what your expected output is?

Comment: i have more than 1000 products which are sold at more than 500 companies at different  price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate relation table like: `price_table` (with attributes `{item_id , cmpny_id, price}`).

You should learn to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you tables.

**Update:** With 1000 items and 500 companies you will have a maximum of 500000 rows. That should take less than 50 MB of storage (including the indexes).

Comment: Ain't that the truth.

Comment: that's right ,but is there any way to add column dynamically?? like show in image . i.e a new column will generate when i add a new company in cmpny table

Comment: @Div94. The idea to add a new column every time a new company is added is a REALLY REALLY BAD design choice. You will have nothing but nightmare scenarios from going this route. The suggestion here to create a table that has `item_id | company_id | price` is much more sound.

Comment: thanxx.. :) for the help